# Vs code order of autocomplete properties and functions

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

Whenever I import a class, and want to autocomplete a property or method of a class, VS code's autocomplete shows my properties and methods all the way at the bottom of the suggestions:

[image]

Is there any way for me to change this order? Or to remove all the other suggestions in this list? I only want to see relevant suggestions, not "global" suggestions.